# Why do I encounter Internal Server Error while converting MySql TO MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

- I've tried searching for answers and used some tutorials, but nothing
  has helped.
- I can successfully establish a connection to my database.
- But when I try to run this query, I get `500-Internal Server Error`.

The code I am using is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows):
  $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
  $id = $row['id'];   
  $position = $row['position'];
else:
  die("User not found.");
endif;
```

How I used to do it using MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0):
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $id = $row['id'];   
  $position = $row['position'];
else:
  die("User not found.");
endif;
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

EDIT: The following code is at the start of my file:

```
// Connection Details
  $host = "";
  $user = "";    
  $pass = "";
  $db = "";

  // Database Connection
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

  // check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
  }
```

Could you please tell me the best way to replicate the MySQL code I posted in MySQLi?

Comment: Where and how are you declaring `$conn`? Have you checked your server logs for error?

Comment: What particular answer and what particular tutorial did you try and what particular part you were unable to adopt?

Comment: In PHP, a 500 error means "go look in your error log". The details of the error (usually a PHP fatal error) will be spelled out there. But better, always when developing code, crank up error reporting and display errors immediately on screen.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I modified my original post to answer your question.